# TRIM function with wildcard in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard, trim

I am working on [Yelp Dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset).The following is the ER diagram of Yelp Dataset from coursera course.

[ER Diagram of Yelp Dataset from Coursera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHe0X.png)

In the entity (Hours), the attribute (hours) contains date and time data for businesses'open hours.   (For example, Monday|12:00-23:00). I would like to extract the hours from this data.

I came across sample code to extract using TRIM()function with wildcard in sql. I don't understand how the wildcard works inside Trim function in sqlite. For example: "%MondayTuesWednesThursFriSatSun|%" in TRIM(H.hours,"%MondayTuesWednesThursFriSatSun|%"). It removes Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday,Friday,Saturday, Sunday from the data in hours attribute.

**Data from hours attribute in Hours Entity**

| hours |
| --- |
| Monday 12:00-23:00 |
| Tuesday 9:00-19:00 |

**Sample Code**

```
SELECT B.name as B_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN H.hours LIKE '%monday%' 
                     THEN TRIM(H.hours,"%MondayTuesWednesThursFriSatSun|%") END) AS Mon_hours
  FROM business B
       INNER JOIN hours H ON B.id = H.business_id
 GROUP BY B.id;
```

**Results**

| Business Name | Monday_hours |
| --- | --- |
| Flaming Kitchen | 12:00-23:00 |
| Freeman's Car Stereo | 9:00-19:00 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested REPLACE() functions for each weekday like this:

```
SELECT (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(H.hours, 'Monday|', ''), 'Tuesday|', ''), 'Wednesday|', ''), 'Thursday|', ''), 'Friday|', ''), 'Saturday|', ''), 'Sunday|', '') )AS Mon_hours
FROM business B 
INNER JOIN hours H ON B.id = H.business_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The TRIM() function in SQLite will remove characters from the first parameter.

Example:

```
select trim('abcdefghij','acgij');
```

- This will remove `a` because the first argument starts with an `a`, but will not remove the `c` because the `b` remains.
- In the end of the string `j` and `i` gets removed, but `g` is not removed because the letter `h` remains.

The result will be: `bcdefgh`